# asp.net change language using masterPage hyperlink

Tags: c#, hyperlink, master-pages, translation

Suppose I have the child page with the following hyperlink

```
http://localhost:7621/PDWv1.0.4/ProductList.aspx?categoryID=2
```

And Page Load of the ProductList.aspx is as follows ( section for Page_Load )

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        l_categoryParseId = Request.QueryString["categoryID"];
        if (l_categoryParseId == null || l_categoryParseId.Trim() == null ||
            l_categoryParseId == "" || l_categoryParseId.Trim() == "")
        {
            l_productlist = l_access.getProductList(-1, lang);
        }
        else
        {
            int categoryID = Int32.Parse(l_categoryParseId.ToString());
            l_productlist = l_access.getProductList(categoryID, lang);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < l_productlist.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            String path = "http://www.newrising.com.hk";
            String httpPath = path + l_productlist.Rows[i]["productPhoto"].ToString();
            l_productlist.Rows[i]["productPhoto"] = httpPath;
        }

        listViewProductList.DataSource = l_productlist;
        listViewProductList.DataBind();

       // GridViewProductList.DataSource = l_productlist;
        //GridViewProductList.PageSize = 10;
        //GridViewProductList.AllowPaging = true;
        //GridViewProductList.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(GridViewProductList_ItemCommand);
        //GridViewProductList.DataBind();   
    }
```

And the hyperlink for the masterpage changing panguages:

MasterPage.aspx

```
     <asp:HyperLink ID="linkChi" runat="Server"                           
                       ImageUrl="images/chinese.png"  />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="linkEng" runat="Server"                           
                        ImageUrl="images/english.png" />
```

MasterPage.aspx.cs

```
    linkChi.NavigateUrl = "?currentculture=zh-hk";
linkEng.NavigateUrl = "?currentculture=en-us";
```

Whenever I press linkChi or linkEng to switch the languages , it shows the page is blank ..

Would you please tell me how to ensure the value of categoryID can be retained under page postback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not get what your problem is but if you are asking how to hold the value after post-back you can always use

```
ViewState["categoryID"] = categoryID;
```

Comment: I am trying to change language if I press the hyperlinks